# How to retrieve both @elapsed and @allocated as floats simultaneously in julia?

Tags: profiling, julia

I would like to use retrieve both the bytes allocated and seconds used for my function in `julia`. Right now I can get each number separately, but I would like to do something like

```
@elapsed, @allocated f(1)
```

to get both numbers for the same call on my function.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `@timed`?

```
julia> @timed(f(1))
(0.8414709848078965, 0.012771058, 76527, 0.0, Base.GC_Diff(76527, 0, 0, 1351, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

# the first three values are result, elapsed and allocated, so
julia> (x, elapsed, alloced) = @timed(f(1))[1:3]
(0.8414709848078965, 0.012771058, 76527)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some quick fix with a macro using `@elapsed` and `@allocated`:

```
macro timemem(ex)
    return quote begin 
        local t,m
        m = @allocated t = @elapsed $(esc(ex))
        t,m-2*sizeof(Int)
    end end
end
```

This is not the best test case, but it gives the same answer as the macros from Base:

```
julia> @timemem sleep(1.0)
(1.002348175, 192)
```